# Using GroupBy in linq to group the letters of a string

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying to go into a file extract the words in the file and group each letter in the string of the file. The grouping should be ordered by its letter(a,b,c,d, ect..) and then count each letter and present a count of each letter to the console, something like this:

a: 56
b: 34
c: 53
d:

So I am working with the following code but I don't think it's working the way I want it to, does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
        var upper = text.ToUpper();
        var alpha = upper.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray();
        var grouped = alpha.GroupBy(i => i % 26);
        var a = grouped.First(g => g.Key == 0).Count();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
var dictionary = new Dictionary<char,int>();
//count every letter
foreach (var symbol in text)
{
    //skip non letter characters
    if (!char.IsLetter(symbol))
         continue;

    var key = char.ToLower(symbol);
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
         dictionary[key]++;
    else
         dictionary.Add(key,1);
}
//result output
foreach (var pair in dictionary.OrderBy(p => p.Key))
{
    Console.Write("{0}: {1} ", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

It's not smallest solution, but better then grouping in terms of resource usage.

Answer (score 11):

You need a `Select` after the `GroupBy` to get the results you need:

```
var result = text
    .ToUpper()
    .Where(char.IsLetter)
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(g => new { Letter = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Then to format the results as `"a: 56 b: 34 c: 53"` you can use `string.Join` and `string.Format`:

```
string formattedResult = string.Join(" ", result.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.Letter, x.Count)));
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I think you should add result letters ordering

Answer (score 0):

You're operating on letters, not words.

You need `Split(' ')`, to get a sequence of strings with the individual words.

You can then group by the first letter in each word.